# Children/Parent cakephp

Tags: cakephp

No código abaixo, tenho um `Select`, que retorna todas minhas acomodações que estão com `parent_id null`, que no caso seriam todas as acomodações *PAI*. Mas, na hora de retornar, preciso que mostre A acomodação *PAI* e os seus *children*.

Ex.: Quarto - banheiro - cama - almoço.

Como faço para obter os *children* de cada acomodação *PAI*?

Parte do form select:

```
  <?= $this->Form->input('acomodacao',array(
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => $acomodacoes,
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'empty' => 'Escolha uma acomodação'
                            )); 
                        ?>
```

Código que faz a consulta no controller:

```
 $acomodacoes = $this->Navigation->find('list',array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'parent_id' => null,
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Navigation.nome',
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: Você quer simplesmente obter uma lista "corrida" de itens destes pais sem qualquer agrupamento? Ou utilizar os grupos do `<select>` para formatar de forma que fique segmentado?

Comment: Só quero que mostre no select, os demais children que fazer parte do pai.
Porque quando eu for salvar, o id que vai pro banco de dados será apenas o id do pai.
Já tentei com getPath, mas não funcionou..

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você precisa de algo assim no seu `Controller`:

```
$acomodacoes = $this->Navigation->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'parent_id <>' => null,
        ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Navigation.parent_id',
        'Navigation.nome'
        ),
    ));
```

Ou seja, você vai obter uma lista de itens que possuem `parent_id` (logo, todos que tem um pai) e o seu `<select>` terá opções com o `value` sendo o `parent_id` e o texto de exibição o próprio nome.